# Rooting android with the dirty pipe vulnerability

Tags: rooting, root-access, linux, magisk

there is a newly discovered Linux Vulnerability has which lets you inject code in root processes [(source)](https://dirtypipe.cm4all.com/), i have been looking into it but failed to pull anything off, for what i understand to gain root access we have to inject the su binary or (magisk?) into the file system, i have made a elf executable to run it on my phone but not much more, if someone who knows more than me, who can figure out how to use this to root the phone it would be nice.

It's just curiosity and I know this wont be a very efficient way to gain root but could be great for devices with locked boot-loaders like huawey devices.

Comment: `Due to the fact that Linux kernel version 5.8 (or above) has only been an Android option since Android 12, legacy devices aren’t affected.` https://www.xda-developers.com/dirty-pipe-linux-vulnerability-root-android/

Comment: I know, and i have a compatible device.